# How to randomize XML Elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have an XML like this:

```
<Configuration>
    <Elements>
        <SubElement1></SubElement1>
        <SubElement2></SubElement2>
        <SubElement3></SubElement3>
    </Elements>
</Configuration>
```

Now each and every time I read XML, I want to change ordering of `SubElements`randomly as mentioned below.

```
<Configuration>
    <Elements>
        <SubElement2></SubElement2>
        <SubElement1></SubElement1>
        <SubElement3></SubElement3>
    </Elements>
</Configuration>
```

But I could not find possible solutions for this

Comment: Where is the xml stored?

Comment: It is stored on physical location. And I want it to transfer on SFTP server. But before this operation, I want to randomize elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could randomize the xml like this.

```
public class Xml
{
    public static string XmlString = @"<Configuration>
<Elements>
    <SubElement1></SubElement1>
    <SubElement2></SubElement2>
    <SubElement3></SubElement3>
</Elements>
</Configuration>";

    public static XDocument Randomize()
    {
        //rather keep a static random if u can
        var rand = new Random();

        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(XmlString);
        var ele = xdoc.Root.Element("Elements");

        var shuffle = new XElement("Elements", ele.Elements().OrderBy(x => rand.Next()));

        ele.ReplaceWith(shuffle);
        return xdoc;
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks :)